# Describe the map $\text{Tor}_1^R (k,k)\otimes \text{Tor}_1^R(k,k)\to\text{Tor}_2^R(k,k)$.

Tags: homological-algebra

> Let $R=k[x,y]$, describe the map $\text{Tor}_1^R (k,k)\otimes \text{Tor}_1^R(k,k)\to\text{Tor}_2^R(k,k)$.

The Koszul complex gives a projective resolution of $k$:
$$
0\to R\stackrel{\binom{-y}{x}}{\longrightarrow} R\oplus R\stackrel{(x\ \ y)}{\longrightarrow}R\to k\to 0.
$$
Thus, for $R$-module $k$, by computing the homology of 
$$
0\to k\stackrel{0}{\to} k\oplus k\stackrel{0}{\to} k\to 0,
$$
we have $\text{Tor}_0^R=k$, $\text{Tor}_1^R=k\oplus k$, $\text{Tor}_2^R=k$.

---

Could you please help me to proceed? Thanks.